# Trying to read a complex json file in javascript

Tags: json

I am trying to read the following json file to extract the traffic information but some how I am not getting it.

```js
{"success":true,"variables":{"details":true,"polylines":true,"polylineBounds":true,"totals":true,"filterDetails":true,"filterPolylines":true},"dateTime":"2017-03-03T20:39:00.000Z","roads":[{"road":"A1","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Amsterdam","end":"Amersfoort","roadworks":[{"id":64251658,"road":"A1","segmentId":3000,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Diemen-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":52.34558,"lon":4.97739},"to":"Naarden-West","toLoc":{"lat":52.30712,"lon":5.12852},"polyline":"}go~Hayi]fBoGhBqGrEqNlBwFjByE`BsD`AqBxAkC~BuDbDsEjJqL`CiDtBgDhB_DtCuFrBoEdCyFbCiGdAaDzA_F~AeGvAuG`AmF~@_G`BwLn@uFZaDh@_H\\iGT}FJ_EDcDDcH?gFGqP@wFCm@CiHDuOT}D`AyFn@{Eh@gJFeGGaB[gDa@oHg@kFKiF?aNAeNBmj@ByDJeFPaEX{Db@}Dp@{Ev@_FdBkJj@sC`DsNjAcFtFkTfC}KhGoZlB_K~AaJlBoL|BqMxR}cAvCcOzH}`@lB{KdByIvAqHtB}JbDoQnB}KhAiGbCqMvBoK`CqKrBkIlFoSv@oCfRis@z@gD~@gEv@eEVeBXqBZ}Ch@oHLyDFsD","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.30562,"lon":4.97057},"northEast":{"lat":52.34831,"lon":5.13587}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-10T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-13T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 10 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 13 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Amersfoort","end":"Amsterdam","roadworks":[{"id":64251694,"road":"A1","segmentId":3000,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Muiderberg","fromLoc":{"lat":52.31497,"lon":5.10514},"to":"Diemen-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":52.34558,"lon":4.97739},"polyline":"g~g~Hauf^aCtImBjHwBzIiBdIqBjKwA~G_CtM{@jEcDbQ_AzE{DbT_DnPwAzHyGh]SlBsA|I[tCo@pHyAfQy@bL{AvYg@bIq@zIw@lIkCjUqAxJs@hEy@nEgAdEoD|QyDlSyCtQmEtYqCzSsCvUcBvOeB~PmDdc@o@tIo@vLYtHQ|IEtEIpAE~UFrLBdSIhM_@lPShFMlBq@~Hm@xFe@~De@bDiAfHm@bDu@tDqA~FoA`FsAxEsDdLeDjIwA`DkClFkAxBmB`DiEpGyBtC}FlHsDfF_BhCgAjByAvCwAzC","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.31092,"lon":4.97845},"northEast":{"lat":52.34515,"lon":5.11841}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-10T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-13T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 10 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 13 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A2","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Utrecht","end":"Amsterdam","jams":[{"id":2874308,"road":"A2","segmentId":3105,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","fromLoc":{"lat":52.29844,"lon":4.94386},"to":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","toLoc":{"lat":52.29844,"lon":4.94386},"events":[{"alertC":478,"text":"Verbindingsweg dicht"},{"alertC":701,"text":"Wegwerkzaamheden"}],"reason":"Verbindingsweg dicht. Wegwerkzaamheden."}]},{"start":"Amsterdam","end":"Utrecht","jams":[{"id":2874307,"road":"A2","segmentId":3105,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","fromLoc":{"lat":52.29575,"lon":4.94041},"to":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","toLoc":{"lat":52.29575,"lon":4.94041},"events":[{"alertC":478,"text":"Verbindingsweg dicht"},{"alertC":701,"text":"Wegwerkzaamheden"}],"reason":"Verbindingsweg dicht. Wegwerkzaamheden."}]},{"start":"Eindhoven","end":"Maastricht","jams":[{"id":2874311,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Leenderheide","fromLoc":{"lat":51.40191,"lon":5.50359},"to":"afrit Valkenswaard","toLoc":{"lat":51.34987,"lon":5.54248},"polyline":"}duxHmnr`@nKmDpFeBzI{CnTaHdQ{FfBs@xBcAxAw@nEsC~BgBfCwBlL{KvAmAbcAg_ArO}N~f@od@pQuPjD{CxBkBrC{BlEeDvBiBlH{FfAaAlAoAtAaBlAcBtAyB","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.3474,"lon":5.50647},"northEast":{"lat":51.39551,"lon":5.54508}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"},{"alertC":701,"text":"Wegwerkzaamheden"}],"reason":"Dicht. Wegwerkzaamheden."},{"id":2873561,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"accident","incidentType":"stationary-traffic","from":"Sint Joost","fromLoc":{"lat":51.13471,"lon":5.89665},"to":"Echt","toLoc":{"lat":51.10561,"lon":5.85314},"polyline":"}mawHag~b@`CfBvBfBpAlAvCzC`BnBvBpCfCtDnCrEzCfGv@bBbB~Dba@|cArGzOxEtK~ExJvBbEzFzJ","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.11333,"lon":5.86563},"northEast":{"lat":51.13071,"lon":5.89441}},"events":[{"alertC":505,"text":"Twee rijstroken zijn dicht"},{"alertC":204,"text":"Door een ongeluk met een vrachtwagen"},{"alertC":101,"text":"Stilstaand verkeer","distance":2000}],"distance":2000,"delay":900,"start":"2017-03-03T19:25:00.000Z","reason":"Twee rijstroken zijn dicht. Door een ongeluk met een vrachtwagen."}],"roadworks":[{"id":65008319,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Valkenswaard","fromLoc":{"lat":51.34987,"lon":5.54248},"to":"afrit Valkenswaard","toLoc":{"lat":51.34987,"lon":5.54248},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.34678,"lon":5.54006},"northEast":{"lat":51.35262,"lon":5.54611}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T10:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 11:00 uur."},{"id":65008287,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Leende","fromLoc":{"lat":51.33866,"lon":5.56659},"to":"Leende","toLoc":{"lat":51.33866,"lon":5.56659},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.33678,"lon":5.56639},"northEast":{"lat":51.33861,"lon":5.57136}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T10:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 11:00 uur."},{"id":65008525,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Maarheeze","fromLoc":{"lat":51.3123,"lon":5.60601},"to":"Maarheeze","toLoc":{"lat":51.3123,"lon":5.60601},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.31017,"lon":5.6036},"northEast":{"lat":51.31443,"lon":5.60828}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T10:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 11:00 uur."},{"id":65008291,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Budel","fromLoc":{"lat":51.29803,"lon":5.6271},"to":"afrit Budel","toLoc":{"lat":51.29803,"lon":5.6271},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.29461,"lon":5.62468},"northEast":{"lat":51.29908,"lon":5.63383}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 06:00 uur."},{"id":65008351,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Weert-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":51.2763,"lon":5.66674},"to":"Weert-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":51.2763,"lon":5.66674},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.27616,"lon":5.65911},"northEast":{"lat":51.27791,"lon":5.67119}},"events":[{"alertC":474,"text":"Afrit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Afrit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 06:00 uur."},{"id":63519087,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Maarheeze","fromLoc":{"lat":51.3123,"lon":5.60601},"to":"Weert-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":51.2763,"lon":5.66674},"polyline":"u{vxH_vp`@z@yEjAmEpAqDjAuCp@qAv@uAtAsBxAkB~@_AlAgA~AkAlAs@jCsAnBw@xIuCnAYvFoB~PuF`GuBdd@wNhDkAfBs@xBcAxAw@nEsC~BgBfCwBlL{KvAmAbcAg_ArO}N~f@od@pQuPjD{CxBkBrC{BlEeDvBiBlH{FfAaAtB{BzByCxA_CjBqDd@cA`AgCz@mC`f@caB~G}UtAaFpBuH|Qut@b@aB`AsC~@aCl@uAhBkDhBoClAcBlxAgmBbC}C`AkA|@_ArBsBhAaAdFeFjE_FxIkKnE}E`]y\\rBcC|@kAtAwBl@gAjB{DpAaDjjAmyCxAoDn@yAlBeDzAqBz@aAdAaAtAiAlGsExCeCzC}ChBwB~B}C|FqItDaGbCiE~CaG`CyErDeIzAmDl@gB|@sCjAoEn@sCh@wCb@mCl@wE^}Df@aIPaGD{CAiGIqFGcB","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.27616,"lon":5.49744},"northEast":{"lat":51.40427,"lon":5.67119}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 06:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A8","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Zaandam","end":"Amsterdam","roadworks":[{"id":65008622,"road":"A8","segmentId":3452,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Zaandijk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.46387,"lon":4.80818},"to":"Zaandijk","toLoc":{"lat":52.46387,"lon":4.80818},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.46327,"lon":4.80552},"northEast":{"lat":52.46448,"lon":4.81089}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T22:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 23:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A9","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Diemen","end":"Amstelveen","roadworks":[{"id":65008965,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Bijlmermeer","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"to":"Bijlmermeer","toLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.3048,"lon":4.96248},"northEast":{"lat":52.31095,"lon":4.98022}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T21:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 22:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Amstelveen","end":"Alkmaar","roadworks":[{"id":63020027,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Haarlem-Zuid","fromLoc":{"lat":52.37293,"lon":4.71035},"to":"knp. Rottepolderplein","toLoc":{"lat":52.38439,"lon":4.70737},"polyline":"kks~Huhx[sCxGuDjI_G|MsAlCeA~AmAtAe@b@s@h@{@d@g@Vm@TcAVcBR{ANiFZyIr@mJfAuCRcD\\sf@fEsIj@","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.36934,"lon":4.70665},"northEast":{"lat":52.39025,"lon":4.71707}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T23:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 5 maart 2017 00:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":64156557,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Raasdorp","fromLoc":{"lat":52.35687,"lon":4.73999},"to":"knp. Rottepolderplein","toLoc":{"lat":52.38439,"lon":4.70737},"polyline":"cuo~Hmd_\\iJvSeJ|SgH~Oel@~rAmE`KcBvDaXtm@iJjTuDjI_G|MsAlCa@p@u@dA{@|@e@b@wA`A_Ad@m@TcAVo@JoCViFZyIr@mJfAuCRcD\\sf@fEsIj@","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.35042,"lon":4.70665},"northEast":{"lat":52.39025,"lon":4.75223}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-12T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 12 maart 2017 01:00 uur tot 12 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":64670523,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Rottepolderplein","fromLoc":{"lat":52.38439,"lon":4.70737},"to":"de Wijkertunnel","toLoc":{"lat":52.45815,"lon":4.67059},"polyline":"upu~H_qv[_EZcD\\sf@fE_Kp@mTtB{k@bFoCZeC^qDt@mD~@{DpAiFjBsm@xWqGzCgCxAyBxAwAdA_DlC_C|B_ChCiB~BmBjCkAfBiB|CcCrEmCxF}K|VqAlC{BhEu@pAcC~DoBrCqAhB}D~EwA~AsG`Hya@|b@wAfBiEhEqBlB{BnByAjAaCbB_BbAqBhA{BdAsDxAaCt@yD|@_En@eDXcDL}A@yBA}BIwDYgEq@eB_@_Cm@oVyHcAa@q@QcDaA}A_@gBm@eCs@mFiB{B}@mEeBuCsA","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.38043,"lon":4.66701},"northEast":{"lat":52.46138,"lon":4.70816}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T22:30:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 23:30 uur tot 5 maart 2017 06:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Alkmaar","end":"Amstelveen","roadworks":[{"id":64156522,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Heemskerk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.50888,"lon":4.70739},"to":"knp. Beverwijk","toLoc":{"lat":52.48608,"lon":4.69237},"polyline":"u~n_Iyvv[hCxCbClCzD~DlDfDfDrCdHlF~FvDvElC`ClApCrAzErBfDlAvDnAlGfB|HhClHvCzIfEjE~B`BbAfF`D~CxBtDrCzIjH","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.48629,"lon":4.69246},"northEast":{"lat":52.51067,"lon":4.70909}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-11T23:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-12T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 12 maart 2017 00:00 uur tot 12 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":64156442,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Beverwijk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.48608,"lon":4.69237},"to":"knp. Velsen","toLoc":{"lat":52.44144,"lon":4.66828},"polyline":"u~n_Iyvv[hCxCbClCzD~DlDfDfDrCdHlF~FvDvElC`ClApCrAzErBfDlAvDnAlGfB|HhClHvCzIfEjE~B`BbAfF`D~CxBtDrCzIjH","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.48629,"lon":4.69246},"northEast":{"lat":52.51067,"lon":4.70909}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T22:55:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 23:55 uur tot 5 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Amstelveen","end":"Diemen","roadworks":[{"id":65008885,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"to":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","toLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.29985,"lon":4.94788},"northEast":{"lat":52.30117,"lon":4.95308}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65072843,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"to":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","toLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.29985,"lon":4.94788},"northEast":{"lat":52.30117,"lon":4.95308}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65008795,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Bijlmermeer","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"to":"Bijlmermeer","toLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.30658,"lon":4.96777},"northEast":{"lat":52.30911,"lon":4.9752}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65008731,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Weesp","fromLoc":{"lat":52.31343,"lon":4.98834},"to":"Weesp","toLoc":{"lat":52.31343,"lon":4.98834},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.31279,"lon":4.98604},"northEast":{"lat":52.31384,"lon":4.98931}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":63019294,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"to":"knp. Diemen","toLoc":{"lat":52.33386,"lon":4.99969},"polyline":"ccg~Hqgi]aBkH{Z{oAcBuHsDiRyB_KwBmI}@_D_BiFwBmGkDmJwAiD{AcDyBoEsA_CkC{D}A{Ag@m@oCgEyAoBwAeB}@eBi@q@aDsCoAaAsGsEsEeEwAwAcC}C_CoD}AqCeDaHsAoD_AmCiCsI{@cD}@uEo@wDiBkP]qE_@aII_DEcG","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.30658,"lon":4.96777},"northEast":{"lat":52.33171,"lon":5.02445}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A13","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Den Haag","end":"Rotterdam","roadworks":[{"id":65073006,"road":"A13","segmentId":3040,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Delft-Zuid","fromLoc":{"lat":51.99687,"lon":4.3889},"to":"Delft-Zuid","toLoc":{"lat":51.99687,"lon":4.3889},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.9913,"lon":4.38634},"northEast":{"lat":52.00239,"lon":4.39107}},"events":[{"alertC":475,"text":"De afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-03T22:59:00.000Z","reason":"De afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 3 maart 2017 23:59 uur."},{"id":65009143,"road":"A13","segmentId":3040,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Overschie","fromLoc":{"lat":51.93663,"lon":4.43231},"to":"Overschie","toLoc":{"lat":51.93663,"lon":4.43231},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.93206,"lon":4.4329},"northEast":{"lat":51.93593,"lon":4.43761}},"events":[{"alertC":474,"text":"Afrit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-02T21:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Afrit dicht. Van 2 maart 2017 tot 4 maart 2017 dagelijks tussen 22:00 uur en 06:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A22","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Beverwijk","end":"Velsen","roadworks":[{"id":65072631,"road":"A22","segmentId":3463,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Beverwijk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.47364,"lon":4.65357},"to":"Beverwijk","toLoc":{"lat":52.47364,"lon":4.65357},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.47195,"lon":4.65213},"northEast":{"lat":52.47653,"lon":4.65612}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T23:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 5 maart 2017 00:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A32","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Heerenveen","end":"Meppel","roadworks":[{"id":65072771,"road":"A32","segmentId":3240,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Meppel-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"to":"Meppel-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.70073,"lon":6.20649},"northEast":{"lat":52.70535,"lon":6.20836}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65009425,"road":"A32","segmentId":3240,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Meppel-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"to":"Meppel-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"polyline":"m_u`Iqe{d@dIaClLwDpBi@t@Q","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.70073,"lon":6.20649},"northEast":{"lat":52.70535,"lon":6.20836}},"events":[{"alertC":477,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T18:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 19:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A50","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Arnhem","end":"Apeldoorn","roadworks":[{"id":65072914,"road":"A50","segmentId":3341,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Loenen","fromLoc":{"lat":52.14013,"lon":5.99024},"to":"Apeldoorn","toLoc":{"lat":52.20747,"lon":6.02141},"polyline":"eef}Hmepc@cPe_@oDaIkIuQiEcJqK{T{ImQaMgVkDoGgD}F}BuDkCaEqDiFuGwI{E_GyCgDmEuEiCeCcC}BeHcG_BqAaI}FgDwBcDoBaGeDoCsA}DkBaEcBaFiBqDmAsBk@aE_AeC_@{BWgDS_DGiB@sBFmBJwANgDb@oCj@_Cj@oDjAsBz@sExBmo@|[sFlCaCfAgBp@aBl@sBl@sEfAkBXyAPsETeFDwBEiEY{Ca@eB[_PgD_i@{K_F}@sDi@","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.13795,"lon":5.98631},"northEast":{"lat":52.2121,"lon":6.02821}},"events":[{"alertC":483,"text":"De hoofdrijbaan is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T21:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T06:30:00.000Z","reason":"De hoofdrijbaan is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 22:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 07:30 uur."}]},{"start":"Oss","end":"Eindhoven","roadworks":[{"id":64155931,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Oss-Oost","fromLoc":{"lat":51.72743,"lon":5.57317},"to":"Oss-Oost","toLoc":{"lat":51.72743,"lon":5.57317},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.72751,"lon":5.57318},"northEast":{"lat":51.72805,"lon":5.57353}},"events":[{"alertC":406,"text":"De oprit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De oprit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155804,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Paalgraven","fromLoc":{"lat":51.7413,"lon":5.58601},"to":"Oss-Oost","toLoc":{"lat":51.72743,"lon":5.57317},"polyline":"iwxzHq|aa@zCtKj@fB`AfCzAxCn@fAfA|A~AjBxBlBpBlAjCjA~CfA`DpAnEvBdB~@fHdEtPnJ~^pS~C`BjB|@vClAhErArBh@rEv@lAPdBPlBL~BHxC@vCGvCQfBQvCa@zBa@~Aa@pDaAxHcCpLeE`FoBrFcCpLeGbGeDnDkBzB_AhC}@`AWfCg@fAQxAO~AM`BG|FIxBIfAIpASbB]nBq@rAm@rBoA~AoAlAiAj@o@nA_BhBoCbAkBbEwIbDwGnZsl@nBsDxAcCbD_FfCeDhBuBjCkC`CuBzBeB~CuB`DcBfD{AdBm@|Ag@tBi@tCi@lC_@lAMvHk@lFSrGIxF@rCDzFNjDD|B?tEInFUlDYxMsAhBMpCEnCDjCP`CZdCf@nBf@lC`AxAn@dCpArBpAdCjBnBfBpArAvA|ArBlClAdBvA~BdB`DxB|ErAdDrErMjOrc@fEhMzGtSdAfDvB|H~@~DpA`Hr@jEz@tGp@rG~LbxAdGtt@lFzp@f@tI^bH`@nJXjJVpPDjFDxSFzGLlFXxGb@rGn@|GbAnH`A`G~@jErAlF|AfF|AlEdC`GxAxCdBzCxA|BxBzCrBdCdBhBnAjAvBfBbDbCpA|@|CvAtAj@\\H","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.62212,"lon":5.50238},"northEast":{"lat":51.74149,"lon":5.60047}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155908,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Nistelrode","fromLoc":{"lat":51.71503,"lon":5.5689},"to":"Nistelrode","toLoc":{"lat":51.71503,"lon":5.5689},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.71436,"lon":5.56862},"northEast":{"lat":51.71882,"lon":5.56887}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155886,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Zeeland","fromLoc":{"lat":51.67052,"lon":5.59974},"to":"afrit Zeeland","toLoc":{"lat":51.67052,"lon":5.59974},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.66721,"lon":5.59954},"northEast":{"lat":51.67238,"lon":5.59981}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155860,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Volkel","fromLoc":{"lat":51.65215,"lon":5.59866},"to":"afrit Volkel","toLoc":{"lat":51.65215,"lon":5.59866},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.64808,"lon":5.5944},"northEast":{"lat":51.65172,"lon":5.59843}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155843,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Veghel-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":51.63799,"lon":5.57041},"to":"Veghel-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":51.63799,"lon":5.57041},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.63781,"lon":5.56766},"northEast":{"lat":51.63926,"lon":5.57451}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155960,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Veghel","fromLoc":{"lat":51.62566,"lon":5.50522},"to":"Veghel","toLoc":{"lat":51.62566,"lon":5.50522},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.62212,"lon":5.50238},"northEast":{"lat":51.62766,"lon":5.50727}},"events":[{"alertC":407,"text":"De afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"N256","type":"n","segments":[{"start":"Goes","end":"Zierikzee","roadworks":[{"id":64811923,"road":"N256","segmentId":3151,"codeDirection":2,"type":"n","afrc":3,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"de Zeelandbrug","fromLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"to":"de Zeelandbrug","toLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"polyline":"mf|yH_qrVirEo}G","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.59543,"lon":3.86848},"northEast":{"lat":51.62924,"lon":3.91432}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-06T22:59:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-07T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 6 maart 2017 23:59 uur tot 7 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Zierikzee","end":"Goes","roadworks":[{"id":648119230,"road":"N256","segmentId":3151,"codeDirection":2,"type":"n","afrc":3,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"de Zeelandbrug","fromLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"to":"de Zeelandbrug","toLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"polyline":"ezbzHcp{VriBvoCbhBlmC","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.59543,"lon":3.86847},"northEast":{"lat":51.62931,"lon":3.91442}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-06T22:59:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-07T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 6 maart 2017 23:59 uur tot 7 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]}],"totals":{"a":{"distance":2,"delay":15,"count":4},"n":{"distance":0,"delay":0,"count":0},"other":{"distance":0,"delay":0,"count":0},"all":{"distance":2,"delay":15,"count":4}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Paste here the code you tried please.

Comment: Yes if I try to parse I receive an error

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't work the way you think it does. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working

```
var json = {"success":true,"variables":{"details":true,"polylines":true,"polylineBounds":true,"totals":true,"filterDetails":true,"filterPolylines":true},"dateTime":"2017-03-03T20:39:00.000Z","roads":[{"road":"A1","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Amsterdam","end":"Amersfoort","roadworks":[{"id":64251658,"road":"A1","segmentId":3000,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Diemen-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":52.34558,"lon":4.97739},"to":"Naarden-West","toLoc":{"lat":52.30712,"lon":5.12852},"polyline":"}go~Hayi]fBoGhBqGrEqNlBwFjByE`BsD`AqBxAkC~BuDbDsEjJqL`CiDtBgDhB_DtCuFrBoEdCyFbCiGdAaDzA_F~AeGvAuG`AmF~@_G`BwLn@uFZaDh@_H\\iGT}FJ_EDcDDcH?gFGqP@wFCm@CiHDuOT}D`AyFn@{Eh@gJFeGGaB[gDa@oHg@kFKiF?aNAeNBmj@ByDJeFPaEX{Db@}Dp@{Ev@_FdBkJj@sC`DsNjAcFtFkTfC}KhGoZlB_K~AaJlBoL|BqMxR}cAvCcOzH}`@lB{KdByIvAqHtB}JbDoQnB}KhAiGbCqMvBoK`CqKrBkIlFoSv@oCfRis@z@gD~@gEv@eEVeBXqBZ}Ch@oHLyDFsD","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.30562,"lon":4.97057},"northEast":{"lat":52.34831,"lon":5.13587}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-10T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-13T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 10 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 13 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Amersfoort","end":"Amsterdam","roadworks":[{"id":64251694,"road":"A1","segmentId":3000,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Muiderberg","fromLoc":{"lat":52.31497,"lon":5.10514},"to":"Diemen-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":52.34558,"lon":4.97739},"polyline":"g~g~Hauf^aCtImBjHwBzIiBdIqBjKwA~G_CtM{@jEcDbQ_AzE{DbT_DnPwAzHyGh]SlBsA|I[tCo@pHyAfQy@bL{AvYg@bIq@zIw@lIkCjUqAxJs@hEy@nEgAdEoD|QyDlSyCtQmEtYqCzSsCvUcBvOeB~PmDdc@o@tIo@vLYtHQ|IEtEIpAE~UFrLBdSIhM_@lPShFMlBq@~Hm@xFe@~De@bDiAfHm@bDu@tDqA~FoA`FsAxEsDdLeDjIwA`DkClFkAxBmB`DiEpGyBtC}FlHsDfF_BhCgAjByAvCwAzC","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.31092,"lon":4.97845},"northEast":{"lat":52.34515,"lon":5.11841}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-10T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-13T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 10 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 13 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A2","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Utrecht","end":"Amsterdam","jams":[{"id":2874308,"road":"A2","segmentId":3105,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","fromLoc":{"lat":52.29844,"lon":4.94386},"to":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","toLoc":{"lat":52.29844,"lon":4.94386},"events":[{"alertC":478,"text":"Verbindingsweg dicht"},{"alertC":701,"text":"Wegwerkzaamheden"}],"reason":"Verbindingsweg dicht. Wegwerkzaamheden."}]},{"start":"Amsterdam","end":"Utrecht","jams":[{"id":2874307,"road":"A2","segmentId":3105,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","fromLoc":{"lat":52.29575,"lon":4.94041},"to":"knp. Holendrecht naar de A9 richting Amersfoort","toLoc":{"lat":52.29575,"lon":4.94041},"events":[{"alertC":478,"text":"Verbindingsweg dicht"},{"alertC":701,"text":"Wegwerkzaamheden"}],"reason":"Verbindingsweg dicht. Wegwerkzaamheden."}]},{"start":"Eindhoven","end":"Maastricht","jams":[{"id":2874311,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Leenderheide","fromLoc":{"lat":51.40191,"lon":5.50359},"to":"afrit Valkenswaard","toLoc":{"lat":51.34987,"lon":5.54248},"polyline":"}duxHmnr`@nKmDpFeBzI{CnTaHdQ{FfBs@xBcAxAw@nEsC~BgBfCwBlL{KvAmAbcAg_ArO}N~f@od@pQuPjD{CxBkBrC{BlEeDvBiBlH{FfAaAlAoAtAaBlAcBtAyB","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.3474,"lon":5.50647},"northEast":{"lat":51.39551,"lon":5.54508}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"},{"alertC":701,"text":"Wegwerkzaamheden"}],"reason":"Dicht. Wegwerkzaamheden."},{"id":2873561,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"jams","label":"accident","incidentType":"stationary-traffic","from":"Sint Joost","fromLoc":{"lat":51.13471,"lon":5.89665},"to":"Echt","toLoc":{"lat":51.10561,"lon":5.85314},"polyline":"}mawHag~b@`CfBvBfBpAlAvCzC`BnBvBpCfCtDnCrEzCfGv@bBbB~Dba@|cArGzOxEtK~ExJvBbEzFzJ","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.11333,"lon":5.86563},"northEast":{"lat":51.13071,"lon":5.89441}},"events":[{"alertC":505,"text":"Twee rijstroken zijn dicht"},{"alertC":204,"text":"Door een ongeluk met een vrachtwagen"},{"alertC":101,"text":"Stilstaand verkeer","distance":2000}],"distance":2000,"delay":900,"start":"2017-03-03T19:25:00.000Z","reason":"Twee rijstroken zijn dicht. Door een ongeluk met een vrachtwagen."}],"roadworks":[{"id":65008319,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Valkenswaard","fromLoc":{"lat":51.34987,"lon":5.54248},"to":"afrit Valkenswaard","toLoc":{"lat":51.34987,"lon":5.54248},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.34678,"lon":5.54006},"northEast":{"lat":51.35262,"lon":5.54611}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T10:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 11:00 uur."},{"id":65008287,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Leende","fromLoc":{"lat":51.33866,"lon":5.56659},"to":"Leende","toLoc":{"lat":51.33866,"lon":5.56659},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.33678,"lon":5.56639},"northEast":{"lat":51.33861,"lon":5.57136}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T10:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 11:00 uur."},{"id":65008525,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Maarheeze","fromLoc":{"lat":51.3123,"lon":5.60601},"to":"Maarheeze","toLoc":{"lat":51.3123,"lon":5.60601},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.31017,"lon":5.6036},"northEast":{"lat":51.31443,"lon":5.60828}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T10:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 11:00 uur."},{"id":65008291,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Budel","fromLoc":{"lat":51.29803,"lon":5.6271},"to":"afrit Budel","toLoc":{"lat":51.29803,"lon":5.6271},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.29461,"lon":5.62468},"northEast":{"lat":51.29908,"lon":5.63383}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 06:00 uur."},{"id":65008351,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Weert-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":51.2763,"lon":5.66674},"to":"Weert-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":51.2763,"lon":5.66674},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.27616,"lon":5.65911},"northEast":{"lat":51.27791,"lon":5.67119}},"events":[{"alertC":474,"text":"Afrit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Afrit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 06:00 uur."},{"id":63519087,"road":"A2","segmentId":3102,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Maarheeze","fromLoc":{"lat":51.3123,"lon":5.60601},"to":"Weert-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":51.2763,"lon":5.66674},"polyline":"u{vxH_vp`@z@yEjAmEpAqDjAuCp@qAv@uAtAsBxAkB~@_AlAgA~AkAlAs@jCsAnBw@xIuCnAYvFoB~PuF`GuBdd@wNhDkAfBs@xBcAxAw@nEsC~BgBfCwBlL{KvAmAbcAg_ArO}N~f@od@pQuPjD{CxBkBrC{BlEeDvBiBlH{FfAaAtB{BzByCxA_CjBqDd@cA`AgCz@mC`f@caB~G}UtAaFpBuH|Qut@b@aB`AsC~@aCl@uAhBkDhBoClAcBlxAgmBbC}C`AkA|@_ArBsBhAaAdFeFjE_FxIkKnE}E`]y\\rBcC|@kAtAwBl@gAjB{DpAaDjjAmyCxAoDn@yAlBeDzAqBz@aAdAaAtAiAlGsExCeCzC}ChBwB~B}C|FqItDaGbCiE~CaG`CyErDeIzAmDl@gB|@sCjAoEn@sCh@wCb@mCl@wE^}Df@aIPaGD{CAiGIqFGcB","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.27616,"lon":5.49744},"northEast":{"lat":51.40427,"lon":5.67119}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 06:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A8","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Zaandam","end":"Amsterdam","roadworks":[{"id":65008622,"road":"A8","segmentId":3452,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Zaandijk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.46387,"lon":4.80818},"to":"Zaandijk","toLoc":{"lat":52.46387,"lon":4.80818},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.46327,"lon":4.80552},"northEast":{"lat":52.46448,"lon":4.81089}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T22:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 23:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A9","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Diemen","end":"Amstelveen","roadworks":[{"id":65008965,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Bijlmermeer","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"to":"Bijlmermeer","toLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.3048,"lon":4.96248},"northEast":{"lat":52.31095,"lon":4.98022}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T21:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 22:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Amstelveen","end":"Alkmaar","roadworks":[{"id":63020027,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Haarlem-Zuid","fromLoc":{"lat":52.37293,"lon":4.71035},"to":"knp. Rottepolderplein","toLoc":{"lat":52.38439,"lon":4.70737},"polyline":"kks~Huhx[sCxGuDjI_G|MsAlCeA~AmAtAe@b@s@h@{@d@g@Vm@TcAVcBR{ANiFZyIr@mJfAuCRcD\\sf@fEsIj@","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.36934,"lon":4.70665},"northEast":{"lat":52.39025,"lon":4.71707}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T23:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 5 maart 2017 00:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":64156557,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Raasdorp","fromLoc":{"lat":52.35687,"lon":4.73999},"to":"knp. Rottepolderplein","toLoc":{"lat":52.38439,"lon":4.70737},"polyline":"cuo~Hmd_\\iJvSeJ|SgH~Oel@~rAmE`KcBvDaXtm@iJjTuDjI_G|MsAlCa@p@u@dA{@|@e@b@wA`A_Ad@m@TcAVo@JoCViFZyIr@mJfAuCRcD\\sf@fEsIj@","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.35042,"lon":4.70665},"northEast":{"lat":52.39025,"lon":4.75223}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-12T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 12 maart 2017 01:00 uur tot 12 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":64670523,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Rottepolderplein","fromLoc":{"lat":52.38439,"lon":4.70737},"to":"de Wijkertunnel","toLoc":{"lat":52.45815,"lon":4.67059},"polyline":"upu~H_qv[_EZcD\\sf@fE_Kp@mTtB{k@bFoCZeC^qDt@mD~@{DpAiFjBsm@xWqGzCgCxAyBxAwAdA_DlC_C|B_ChCiB~BmBjCkAfBiB|CcCrEmCxF}K|VqAlC{BhEu@pAcC~DoBrCqAhB}D~EwA~AsG`Hya@|b@wAfBiEhEqBlB{BnByAjAaCbB_BbAqBhA{BdAsDxAaCt@yD|@_En@eDXcDL}A@yBA}BIwDYgEq@eB_@_Cm@oVyHcAa@q@QcDaA}A_@gBm@eCs@mFiB{B}@mEeBuCsA","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.38043,"lon":4.66701},"northEast":{"lat":52.46138,"lon":4.70816}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T22:30:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 23:30 uur tot 5 maart 2017 06:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Alkmaar","end":"Amstelveen","roadworks":[{"id":64156522,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Heemskerk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.50888,"lon":4.70739},"to":"knp. Beverwijk","toLoc":{"lat":52.48608,"lon":4.69237},"polyline":"u~n_Iyvv[hCxCbClCzD~DlDfDfDrCdHlF~FvDvElC`ClApCrAzErBfDlAvDnAlGfB|HhClHvCzIfEjE~B`BbAfF`D~CxBtDrCzIjH","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.48629,"lon":4.69246},"northEast":{"lat":52.51067,"lon":4.70909}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-11T23:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-12T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 12 maart 2017 00:00 uur tot 12 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":64156442,"road":"A9","segmentId":3461,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Beverwijk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.48608,"lon":4.69237},"to":"knp. Velsen","toLoc":{"lat":52.44144,"lon":4.66828},"polyline":"u~n_Iyvv[hCxCbClCzD~DlDfDfDrCdHlF~FvDvElC`ClApCrAzErBfDlAvDnAlGfB|HhClHvCzIfEjE~B`BbAfF`D~CxBtDrCzIjH","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.48629,"lon":4.69246},"northEast":{"lat":52.51067,"lon":4.70909}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T22:55:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 23:55 uur tot 5 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Amstelveen","end":"Diemen","roadworks":[{"id":65008885,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"to":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","toLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.29985,"lon":4.94788},"northEast":{"lat":52.30117,"lon":4.95308}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65072843,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"to":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","toLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.29985,"lon":4.94788},"northEast":{"lat":52.30117,"lon":4.95308}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65008795,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Bijlmermeer","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"to":"Bijlmermeer","toLoc":{"lat":52.30774,"lon":4.97123},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.30658,"lon":4.96777},"northEast":{"lat":52.30911,"lon":4.9752}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65008731,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Weesp","fromLoc":{"lat":52.31343,"lon":4.98834},"to":"Weesp","toLoc":{"lat":52.31343,"lon":4.98834},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.31279,"lon":4.98604},"northEast":{"lat":52.31384,"lon":4.98931}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":63019294,"road":"A9","segmentId":3460,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Amsterdam-Zuidoost","fromLoc":{"lat":52.30051,"lon":4.94963},"to":"knp. Diemen","toLoc":{"lat":52.33386,"lon":4.99969},"polyline":"ccg~Hqgi]aBkH{Z{oAcBuHsDiRyB_KwBmI}@_D_BiFwBmGkDmJwAiD{AcDyBoEsA_CkC{D}A{Ag@m@oCgEyAoBwAeB}@eBi@q@aDsCoAaAsGsEsEeEwAwAcC}C_CoD}AqCeDaHsAoD_AmCiCsI{@cD}@uEo@wDiBkP]qE_@aII_DEcG","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.30658,"lon":4.96777},"northEast":{"lat":52.33171,"lon":5.02445}},"events":[{"alertC":402,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A13","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Den Haag","end":"Rotterdam","roadworks":[{"id":65073006,"road":"A13","segmentId":3040,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Delft-Zuid","fromLoc":{"lat":51.99687,"lon":4.3889},"to":"Delft-Zuid","toLoc":{"lat":51.99687,"lon":4.3889},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.9913,"lon":4.38634},"northEast":{"lat":52.00239,"lon":4.39107}},"events":[{"alertC":475,"text":"De afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-03T22:59:00.000Z","reason":"De afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 3 maart 2017 23:59 uur."},{"id":65009143,"road":"A13","segmentId":3040,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Overschie","fromLoc":{"lat":51.93663,"lon":4.43231},"to":"Overschie","toLoc":{"lat":51.93663,"lon":4.43231},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.93206,"lon":4.4329},"northEast":{"lat":51.93593,"lon":4.43761}},"events":[{"alertC":474,"text":"Afrit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-02T21:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T05:00:00.000Z","reason":"Afrit dicht. Van 2 maart 2017 tot 4 maart 2017 dagelijks tussen 22:00 uur en 06:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A22","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Beverwijk","end":"Velsen","roadworks":[{"id":65072631,"road":"A22","segmentId":3463,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Beverwijk","fromLoc":{"lat":52.47364,"lon":4.65357},"to":"Beverwijk","toLoc":{"lat":52.47364,"lon":4.65357},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.47195,"lon":4.65213},"northEast":{"lat":52.47653,"lon":4.65612}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T23:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 5 maart 2017 00:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A32","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Heerenveen","end":"Meppel","roadworks":[{"id":65072771,"road":"A32","segmentId":3240,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Meppel-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"to":"Meppel-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.70073,"lon":6.20649},"northEast":{"lat":52.70535,"lon":6.20836}},"events":[{"alertC":471,"text":"Oprit dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-06T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Oprit dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 6 maart 2017 05:00 uur."},{"id":65009425,"road":"A32","segmentId":3240,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Meppel-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"to":"Meppel-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":52.70365,"lon":6.20724},"polyline":"m_u`Iqe{d@dIaClLwDpBi@t@Q","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.70073,"lon":6.20649},"northEast":{"lat":52.70535,"lon":6.20836}},"events":[{"alertC":477,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T18:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 19:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"A50","type":"a","segments":[{"start":"Arnhem","end":"Apeldoorn","roadworks":[{"id":65072914,"road":"A50","segmentId":3341,"codeDirection":1,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Loenen","fromLoc":{"lat":52.14013,"lon":5.99024},"to":"Apeldoorn","toLoc":{"lat":52.20747,"lon":6.02141},"polyline":"eef}Hmepc@cPe_@oDaIkIuQiEcJqK{T{ImQaMgVkDoGgD}F}BuDkCaEqDiFuGwI{E_GyCgDmEuEiCeCcC}BeHcG_BqAaI}FgDwBcDoBaGeDoCsA}DkBaEcBaFiBqDmAsBk@aE_AeC_@{BWgDS_DGiB@sBFmBJwANgDb@oCj@_Cj@oDjAsBz@sExBmo@|[sFlCaCfAgBp@aBl@sBl@sEfAkBXyAPsETeFDwBEiEY{Ca@eB[_PgD_i@{K_F}@sDi@","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":52.13795,"lon":5.98631},"northEast":{"lat":52.2121,"lon":6.02821}},"events":[{"alertC":483,"text":"De hoofdrijbaan is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-03T21:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-04T06:30:00.000Z","reason":"De hoofdrijbaan is dicht. Van 3 maart 2017 22:00 uur tot 4 maart 2017 07:30 uur."}]},{"start":"Oss","end":"Eindhoven","roadworks":[{"id":64155931,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Oss-Oost","fromLoc":{"lat":51.72743,"lon":5.57317},"to":"Oss-Oost","toLoc":{"lat":51.72743,"lon":5.57317},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.72751,"lon":5.57318},"northEast":{"lat":51.72805,"lon":5.57353}},"events":[{"alertC":406,"text":"De oprit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De oprit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155804,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"knp. Paalgraven","fromLoc":{"lat":51.7413,"lon":5.58601},"to":"Oss-Oost","toLoc":{"lat":51.72743,"lon":5.57317},"polyline":"iwxzHq|aa@zCtKj@fB`AfCzAxCn@fAfA|A~AjBxBlBpBlAjCjA~CfA`DpAnEvBdB~@fHdEtPnJ~^pS~C`BjB|@vClAhErArBh@rEv@lAPdBPlBL~BHxC@vCGvCQfBQvCa@zBa@~Aa@pDaAxHcCpLeE`FoBrFcCpLeGbGeDnDkBzB_AhC}@`AWfCg@fAQxAO~AM`BG|FIxBIfAIpASbB]nBq@rAm@rBoA~AoAlAiAj@o@nA_BhBoCbAkBbEwIbDwGnZsl@nBsDxAcCbD_FfCeDhBuBjCkC`CuBzBeB~CuB`DcBfD{AdBm@|Ag@tBi@tCi@lC_@lAMvHk@lFSrGIxF@rCDzFNjDD|B?tEInFUlDYxMsAhBMpCEnCDjCP`CZdCf@nBf@lC`AxAn@dCpArBpAdCjBnBfBpArAvA|ArBlClAdBvA~BdB`DxB|ErAdDrErMjOrc@fEhMzGtSdAfDvB|H~@~DpA`Hr@jEz@tGp@rG~LbxAdGtt@lFzp@f@tI^bH`@nJXjJVpPDjFDxSFzGLlFXxGb@rGn@|GbAnH`A`G~@jErAlF|AfF|AlEdC`GxAxCdBzCxA|BxBzCrBdCdBhBnAjAvBfBbDbCpA|@|CvAtAj@\\H","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.62212,"lon":5.50238},"northEast":{"lat":51.74149,"lon":5.60047}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155908,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Nistelrode","fromLoc":{"lat":51.71503,"lon":5.5689},"to":"Nistelrode","toLoc":{"lat":51.71503,"lon":5.5689},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.71436,"lon":5.56862},"northEast":{"lat":51.71882,"lon":5.56887}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155886,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Zeeland","fromLoc":{"lat":51.67052,"lon":5.59974},"to":"afrit Zeeland","toLoc":{"lat":51.67052,"lon":5.59974},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.66721,"lon":5.59954},"northEast":{"lat":51.67238,"lon":5.59981}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155860,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"afrit Volkel","fromLoc":{"lat":51.65215,"lon":5.59866},"to":"afrit Volkel","toLoc":{"lat":51.65215,"lon":5.59866},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.64808,"lon":5.5944},"northEast":{"lat":51.65172,"lon":5.59843}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155843,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Veghel-Noord","fromLoc":{"lat":51.63799,"lon":5.57041},"to":"Veghel-Noord","toLoc":{"lat":51.63799,"lon":5.57041},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.63781,"lon":5.56766},"northEast":{"lat":51.63926,"lon":5.57451}},"events":[{"alertC":408,"text":"De op- en afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De op- en afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."},{"id":64155960,"road":"A50","segmentId":3349,"codeDirection":0,"type":"a","afrc":0,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"Veghel","fromLoc":{"lat":51.62566,"lon":5.50522},"to":"Veghel","toLoc":{"lat":51.62566,"lon":5.50522},"bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.62212,"lon":5.50238},"northEast":{"lat":51.62766,"lon":5.50727}},"events":[{"alertC":407,"text":"De afrit is dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-04T20:00:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-05T09:00:00.000Z","reason":"De afrit is dicht. Van 4 maart 2017 21:00 uur tot 5 maart 2017 10:00 uur."}]}]},{"road":"N256","type":"n","segments":[{"start":"Goes","end":"Zierikzee","roadworks":[{"id":64811923,"road":"N256","segmentId":3151,"codeDirection":2,"type":"n","afrc":3,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"de Zeelandbrug","fromLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"to":"de Zeelandbrug","toLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"polyline":"mf|yH_qrVirEo}G","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.59543,"lon":3.86848},"northEast":{"lat":51.62924,"lon":3.91432}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-06T22:59:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-07T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 6 maart 2017 23:59 uur tot 7 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]},{"start":"Zierikzee","end":"Goes","roadworks":[{"id":648119230,"road":"N256","segmentId":3151,"codeDirection":2,"type":"n","afrc":3,"category":"roadworks","label":"closed","incidentType":"road-closed","from":"de Zeelandbrug","fromLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"to":"de Zeelandbrug","toLoc":{"lat":51.61232,"lon":3.89141},"polyline":"ezbzHcp{VriBvoCbhBlmC","bounds":{"southWest":{"lat":51.59543,"lon":3.86847},"northEast":{"lat":51.62931,"lon":3.91442}},"events":[{"alertC":401,"text":"Dicht"}],"start":"2017-03-06T22:59:00.000Z","stop":"2017-03-07T04:00:00.000Z","reason":"Dicht. Van 6 maart 2017 23:59 uur tot 7 maart 2017 05:00 uur."}]}]}],"totals":{"a":{"distance":2,"delay":15,"count":4},"n":{"distance":0,"delay":0,"count":0},"other":{"distance":0,"delay":0,"count":0},"all":{"distance":2,"delay":15,"count":4}}};
```

alert(json.roads[0].segments[0].roadworks[0]);